Vaadin 24 iframe is not scrolling to fragment on first load
I am trying to scroll to the fragment element on first iframe load (default browser behavior when there is #<elementId> in the url), however I have been unsuccessful so far.
In url, there is an id of an element after '#' sign, like: mydomain.com/test#h1_id. I made sure that particular element with h1_id exists in the html that is loaded into iframe.
The way the iframe loads is like this: user clicks an <a> element that has a target of that iframe: <a href="mydomain.com/test#h1_id" target="iframename">2c)</a>.
Iframe looks like this: <iframe style="flex: 1 1 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%;" name="iframename" frameborder="0" id="iframename" slot="secondary"></iframe>.
When it loads it does not scroll to the fragment immediately, but once it is loaded and user clicks on <a> another time, it scrolls.
Minimal example:
Route where the <a> element and <iframe> is present:
@Route("/foo")
public class MyLayout extends VerticalLayout {
    public MyLayout() {
        val anch = new Anchor();
        anch.setTarget("iframename");
        anch.setHref("/goo#h1_id"); // or any other url, in my case it is localhost (same origin, or browsers will show warning/error)
        anch.setText("CLICK ME");
        val iframe = new IFrame();
        iframe.setName("iframename");
        iframe.setId("iframename");
        iframe.setSizeFull();
        add(iframe);
        add(anch);
    }
}

Route to show in iframe:
@Route("/goo")
public class Hello extends VerticalLayout {
    public Hello() {
        // long paragraph so it actually takes some height
        val text = new Span(" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " +
                "Pellentesque molestie ultricies lectus ac rhoncus. Quisque auctor venenatis metus," +
                " et tincidunt elit scelerisque in. Donec a magna eget arcu euismod iaculis. Integer " +
                "eget finibus turpis, sed faucibus ligula. Aliquam sed sodales ligula. Aliquam erat volutpa" +
                "t. In sed aliquam elit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nasc" +
                "etur ridiculus mus. Donec tincidunt est aliquet ullamcorper mollis. Integer id sem eu libero " +
                "euismod facilisis nec id turpis. Nullam ullamcorper feugiat fringilla. Nullam ultricies volutpat d" +
                "ui, eu varius dui condimentum eu. Curabitur in lectus faucibus, pellentesque risus et, semper dui.");
        text.addClassName(LumoUtility.FontSize.XXLARGE);
        val scrollElement = new Span("Element to scroll to");
        scrollElement.setId("h1_id");

        add(text, scrollElement);
    }
}

Behavior that I want to achieve (scroll on first iframe load) the way i described above is functional in Vaadin 8, however when we migrated to 24, it does not work. Are there any ways to make it work? I tried scrolling to it programatically in route constructor or in AfterNavigation, or in BeforeEnter, and using javascript load hooks, however it did not help.

Are you actually using internal view urls for the iframe source?  If so, any reason for using the iframe over hiding/showing content manually?

@DrewHarvey reason behind this is historical. Data is hard-coded in in plain HTML String in database and I need to show it. Refactoring would be very expensive. Yes, it is bad.

I created a ticket for this issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/20206#issuecomment-2407759708
